# APISPA.dll, how can I use it with python?

Tags: python, dll

I have this DLL to be used with some hardware in some sort of automatic test equipment, the manufacturer said is a WinDLL, I tried to use it with python using ctypes

import ctypes

myAPI = ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\Windows\\System32\\APISPA.dll")

and gived me an error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\New_ATE_ongoing\LCDCDU174101_test1.py", line 30, in <module>
    myAPI = ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\Windows\\System32\\APISPA.dll")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Can you help me?